# When a country exploits other people / countries

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I know that [exploit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exploit)  means: to use **someone** unfairly for your own advantage / benefit.

for instance as far as I know, one can say:

> - That boss exploits his employees. (meaning that he takes advantage of them and does not pay them sufficiently.)

But what about a country which takes advantage from a country to its own end? How would a native say the following sentence:

> - That country has **exploited** lots of / many African and Asian countries for centuries.

Is the bold verb above the word you would use here? I would be thankful if you help me with it.

Comment: Your dictionary answers this question. The verb **exploit** does not apply only to persons, and no dictionary defines it that way.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: To be fair to A-friend, the dictionary in his link says "to use **someone** unfairly" and the Oxford dictionary says "Benefit unfairly from the work of **someone**..".

Comment: The "entirely answerable with a dictionary" close reason is mainly to prevent people from posting questions without consulting a dictionary first.  A-friend has consulted a dictionary and still isn't quite sure, so if you think the definition works here, you can put that in an answer instead of a close vote.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed - if a dictionary definition is confusing to a learner and they explain the reason why it is confusing them, I think that is a good question for the site. @P.E.Dant

Comment: I almost always do provide a dictionary link, but in this case our OP seems to have ignored the link he himself posted. The very **first** definition there is: **to use something for your own benefit:**
_The two companies joined forces to exploit the potential of the Internet._ This is clear as a bell, and applies perfectly to A-Friend's use! But ColleenV's point is well taken.

Comment: @P.E.Dant It seems obvious to us, but I could imagine that someone might see a distinction between "countries" doing something and "you" or "someone" doing something. I think it's perfectly valid to ask if it is natural to use a particular verb with a country instead of a person, even though we as native speakers think it obviously follows from the definition. Maybe I'm stretching things a bit, but I wonder if it makes more sense to refrain from UVing (or to DV) instead of closing questions where some effort has been made.

Comment: @ColleenV The example given in the first definition is: _The two companies joined forces to exploit the potential of the Internet._ It is difficult to so see how _company_ and _country_ differ here. How would it be natural to apply _exploit_ to a company but not to a country? I agree that we should always err on the side of "leniency," but at the same time it is important to energetically encourage questioners to read and _comprehend_ on their own what the dictionary tells them. Our objective must be to send forth speakers of English who don't need us.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I can't argue with you there - I didn't go look at the actual definition, and I probably should have.

Comment: @ColleenV That's why I was waving my arms and **bolding** and _italicizing_ everything in my comments!

Comment: @P.E.Dant I would write a full mea culpa but I might just make things worse :) I have drama at work and I'm not as focused as I should be.

Comment: @ColleenV In my opinion, you should leave early today and go to the beach. (I'm not a doctor, but I play one on TV.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploited is fine in this sense. It is a very general term to mean taking advantage, however it does not always have a negative connotation.

The following sentences are examples that follow your explanation of the meaning:

> The evil boss exploited his workers by making them work 16 hours per day.
>
> The UK exploits the cheap labour of developing countries.

However without the negative connotation you can use it to just mean taking advantage of something.

> The country found a natural spring beneath the ground and exploited it to produce bottled water.
>
> He discovered he was an excellent fisherman and he exploited this to catch and sell many fish.

Comment: I do think there is a negative connotation in common usage - exploit tends to mean "use unfairly". If you had a positive sense you might want to choose a different word. "He discovered that he was an excellent fisherman and leveraged that to make a lot of money selling fish."

Comment: Perhaps in some cases, but I think that I could say that I exploit the fact I have a big beard to dress up like Santa at Halloween.

Comment: Interestingly, derogation is not the default inference of the _noun,_ but only of the verb. Journalists routinely write and wrote of the exploits of athletes and of Sir Edmund Hillary's exploits in mountaineering.